# "heroku run" gives error "CERT_HAS_EXPIRED: certificate has expired"

Tags: heroku

I get this error trying to run commands on Heroku:

```
$ heroku run pwd -r heroku
Running pwd on ⬢ my-app-name... !
 ▸    CERT_HAS_EXPIRED: certificate has expired
```

I also get this error attempting to open a console with `heroku run rails console`.

Any ideas? It did not help to update the CLI, or to log out from the CLI and back in.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Seems Heroku have an ongoing incident related to this: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/1236

Presumably they will fix it.

Comment: The suggested temporary fix to run commands is:
`heroku run:detached “YOUR COMMAND” –a APP_NAME`

Comment: they say it's fixed but if I `heroku run bash` I still get the same error. I also tried to restart dynos with `heroku restart -a appname` w/o any luck

Comment: I am getting several other errors now including, but not limited to: `ECONNRESET: socket hang up` and `ECONNREFUSED: connect ECONNREFUSED`

Comment: Ditto. Made a support ticket with Heroku; let's see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I am also getting `CERT_HAS_EXPIRED: certificate has expired` on running `heroku run rails console`

I tried with following lines, now its fixed.

`heroku run:detached "heroku run rails c" -a app_name`

`heroku run rails c --app app_name`

Now the issue https://status.heroku.com/incidents/1236 has been resolved.

Comment: putting it here for future incidents: to run a command  (e.g. `rails c`) in detached mode, you should use `heroku run:detached "rails c" -a app_name` instead of `heroku run:detached "heroku run rails c" -a app_name`.

Comment: not fixed for me you guys did something specific like cleaning some cached certificate or is it a propagation time related issue ? I'm on osx in paris thx!

Comment: I need to run `heroku run bash`, so `run:detatched` is not an option for me ;)
I think it takes some time. I'm now getting `ECONNRESET: socket hang up`

Comment: It's working at my end now. I also got ECONNRESET but after waiting a few minutes it came back to normal.